# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException:

Tags: java, mysql, api, jpa, jaxb

How to pass and set the ID in `BetRecordAgEBR`? Please Help me:) Thanks in advance. This is my only problem that encounter. The `BetRecordAgEBR` class is for may database using `jpa`.

```
if ("GR".equals(dataType)) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    aw.getBytes());
    StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(bis);
    brElement = (JAXBElement<T>) jaxbUnmarshaller
                                    .unmarshal(ss, BetRecordAgGR.class);

    ret2 = brElement.getValue();
    counter++;
    if (counter > 100) {
        return brList;
    }
    /*
    *
    * String uuid1 = java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
    * .toString(); dataOpe.setEntityManager(em);
    * ret2.setID(uuid1); dataOpe.add(ret2);
    */
    brList.add((T) ret2);
    System.out.println(brList);
}
```

The Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): us.kirin.bc.BetRecordAgGR
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881)
    at us.kirin.bc.service.DataService.add(DataService.java:40)
    at us.kirin.bc.service.AGServiceTest.BetHistoryAGIN(AGServiceTest.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): us.kirin.bc.BetRecordAgGR
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:826)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:830)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Could you paste full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I change ret2 to BetRecordAgGR ret2;

```
  if ("GR".equals(dataType)) {
     ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                        aw.getBytes());
                                StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(bis);
                                brElement = (JAXBElement<T>) jaxbUnmarshaller
                                        .unmarshal(ss, BetRecordAgGR.class);

                                ret2= (BetRecordAgGR) brElement.getValue();
                                counter++;
                                if (counter > 100) {
                                    return brList;
                                }

                                String uuid1 = java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
                                        .toString();
                                ret2.setID(uuid1);
                                dataOpe.setEntityManager(em);
                                dataOpe.add(ret2);
                                brList.add((T) ret2);
                                System.out.println(brList);
                            }
```